# Sending shortcuts (sendkeys) to another application while control key is down

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, conflict, sendkeys

I have an application in which I can select options in a list which, when selected, give focus to another window and send a shortcut (e.g. focus `Chrome`, and send `Ctrl + 3` to go to the third tab).

This works well, but I can also use a shortcut to quickly select an option in the list **within my own app** (e.g. `Ctrl + 3`).

The issue is that if the user uses a shortcut within my app, then `Ctrl` key is down globally, and sending shortcuts to other application will also have the `Ctrl` key down. (Note that I also send shortcuts to other applications using `Alt` and `Win` keys, so using the same control key in both my app and the target app is not an option)

Is there a way to tell Windows that `Ctrl` is *not* down when using SendKeys, so that the shortcut works in another application? Is there otherwise an alternative for achieving this?

Here is a simplified example of the code I'm using (C#):

```
private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

public void SendCtrl3()
{
    keybd_event(0xA2, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(0x33, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(0x33, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    keybd_event(0xA2, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

Comment: Hmya, this is not just a problem with the Ctrl key.  This goes wrong when the user presses *any* key.  His input will be arbitrarily mixed with yours in a completely unpredictable way.  Certainly a core reason why trying to automate a program with keyboard input is such a fail-whale.  You'll have to uplift this with a UI automation library that can, say, directly poke text into a text box directly.

Comment: You are correct, the issue is for any shortcut in my app triggering a shortcut in another app. Sadly, I can't find APIs for Chrome, Firefox and Notepad++ to switch tabs without resorting to SendKeys, or open the Windows Search charm without using `Win` + `S`... but you might have something there on UI Automation, if I can "click" on a tab, that would solve at least some of my use cases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if the key is physically down, there is no way to make it so other apps won't see that key as down.

The best alternative I found was to use UI Automation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx